# Java - attributevalue from parents child

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm currently working on a small weather API (From YR.NO) in Java.

The API is in XML as shown below:
NOTE : There are several of those "boxes" in the same API, just different time on them.
[Whole XML shown](http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=59.3293235;lon=18.0685808)

```
<time datatype="forecast" from="2016-09-08T21:00:00Z" to="2016-09-08T21:00:00Z">
    <location altitude="47" latitude="59.3293235" longitude="18.0685808">
        <temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="12.0"/>
        <windDirection id="dd" deg="121.8" name="SE"/>
        <windSpeed id="ff" mps="2.2" beaufort="2" name="Svak vind"/>
        <windGust id="ff_gust" mps="3.7"/>
        <humidity value="80.5" unit="percent"/>
        <pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1016.0"/>
        <cloudiness id="NN" percent="51.6"/>
        <fog id="FOG" percent="-0.0"/>
        <lowClouds id="LOW" percent="51.2"/>
        <mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="0.0"/>
        <highClouds id="HIGH" percent="0.8"/>
        <dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="8.8"/>
    </location>
```

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
{
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        String attributeName = attributes.getLocalName(i);
        String attributeValue = attributes.getValue(i);
        System.out.println(attributes.getLocalName(i) + " : " +     attributes.getValue(i));

        //if(attributeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(timeCheck.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        // {
        //  System.out.println("Temperature: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        // }
}
```

With this ^ i can easily display all the Names with their values but I can't really figure out how to control it.
What I have now is a String that saves the user-input like:

```
String timeCheck = "T"+timeUserInput;
```

(If i input 15 then the timeCheck becomes "T15")
and then I check if some value obtains this input for example "T21" with this inside the for-loop:

```
if(attributeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(timeCheck.toLowerCase()) != -1)
```

and then if's true I want to print the value of temperature which in this case is "12.0" but I can't seem to find an easy way of doing it. I can print ALL the temperature values but i ONLY want the temperature value of the right time.

Tried my best explaining my issue, recently started with Java, Thanks in advance! If you need an explanation of anything just tell me and i'll try.

Comment: How are you parsing? XPath? SAX? DOM? JAXB? How are you stuck? Please improve this question if at all possible. My guess is that you do in fact want to use JAXB to convert an XML into valid objects, but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm using SAXParser. I'm stuck because i don't know how to get only this specific value. I will check out what JAXB does!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Like this : http://imgur.com/PSIF3Zj

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SF2ZESr.png, Don't think I'm able to explain anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

To your purposes, I'd recommend you to use XPATH Api, a specific language to query an XML. The program would be like this:

```
public void getTemperature(org.w3c.dom.Document doc)
throws javax.xml.transform.TransformerException, javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException
{
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory xpathFactory=javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance();
    javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath=xpathFactory.newXPath();
    String temperature=(String)xpath.evaluate("product/time[contains(@from,'"+timeCheck+"')]/location/temperature/@value", doc, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING);
}
```